# How do I write a conditional based on search results?

Tags: conditionals, advanced-conditionals

I have a section set up to display contents based on category URL information and it works great. However, when I do a search, the search result URL has a unique value in segment_4 that doesn't fit into any of the designated categories:

> http://rouviere.com/photo/image/fall-colors-alpine-loop-utah9/5918ab43c62403abdef86474b6228f32

In this case I would prefer to hide the conditional content, but I am not sure how to work that segment_4 value into a conditional since it will change with each search return.

I am thinking along the lines of **only display the content if segment_4 is not a number**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood you, but the conditional you mentioned is:

```
{if !(segment_4 ~ "/^\d+$/") } the `segment_4` isn't a number{/if}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Could be slightly more elegant with `{if segment_4 ~ '/^\D*$/'}` as `\D` matches any non-digit.

Comment: My bad! You're right! Please, update it, @Low!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have URL Helper ( https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper ) or Seg2Cat ( http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/ ) installed, I'd suggest installing URL Helper (they both use the same syntax; URL Helper has a few more variables, so that's the one I'd recommend getting; both are free).

Once you've got that, you'll have access to a couple of new variables you can use for some conditionals to test whether or not segment 4 (or any other segment) is a valid category or not.

I suspect you could use something like this...

```
{if "{last_segment_category_id}" == ""}The last segment is not a category{/if}
```

... and work out a way to achieve what you're looking for.